# Syntax Color Highlighting for Bash in Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, vim, syntax-highlighting

I am programming some bash scripts in Terminal with VIM, on OSX 10.8, but there is no syntax-highlighting for bash. How can I enable it?

Comment: Are you talking about syntax highlighting in some editor in terminal (e.g. vim, nano, emacs, etc), or are you talking about highlighting for your prompt (which isn't really syntax highlighting).

Comment: Sorry, I meant for the VIM editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have been using macvim http://code.google.com/p/macvim/ for a long time, it has syntax highlighting. just enable syntax highlighting using ":syntax on" in your .vimrc.

don't forget to make an alias for macvim in your environment. just like this:
alias vim='/Applications/MacVim/mvim'

the stock vim (/usr/bin/vim) should have also has syntax highlighting too.

oh, in case you need full GUI editor, try textmate, it's free now

Comment: Thanks. Same for MacVim as stock Vim , the order :syntax on work pretty well.

By the way, thanks for the suggestion, I'll check textmate out